# Help to explain what Christoffel symbols represent in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, general-relativity

The Christoffel symbols are the array of numbers describing a metric connection in a non-flat surface.

I am unclear and having trouble picturing Christoffel symbols in 4 dimensions used in general relativity, could anyone give some pointers to the simplest/lowest dimension for which Christoffel symbols are defined, please?

**1.** What is the lowest dimension for which Christoffel symbols exist?

**2.** Are there Christoffel symbols in 1 dimension, or if not, in 2 dimensions?

**3.** What does the form of Christoffel symbol look like in 1 dimension (or lowest dimension), and which rate of change in the coordinate bases is it computing?

Thank you for any help/pointers on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to all three questions: in dimension $1$, the Levi-Civita connection has $\Gamma_{00}^0=\frac12g^{00}\partial_0g_{00}$.